# How to convert a line such that it satisfy the the minimum turn radius criteria?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, geospatial

I have a long line (x,y points) and the line is irregular in nature. I need to make this line cleaner such that, the turn radius of every part of the line should be above some specified value. What is the best algorithm to use to perform this? I tried Douglas-Peucker algorithm which is removing jitter from the line but returns a new line with sharp turns where my turn radius condition fails. Please suggest any algorithm/library I can use here. I have this requirement for desktop and mobile development.

Thanks